# Windows 7 installation fails on Samsung RV509 laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

I have a Samsung Intel Pentium RV509 laptop. When I try to install Windows 7 it can't start the installation after copying system files.

I know that in some laptops I have to change a hard setting to be able to do this, but I don't know if this laptop is like them or not. How can I get the installation to continue?

Comment: @moab: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the bios for an ATA, IDE or Compatibility mode, most likely you need a Sata driver to be loaded at the start of setup the way it is currently configured